# 'List<T>.ForEach()' and mutability

Tags: c#, list, foreach, mutability

I want to translate all points in a `List<T>`. This works:

```
for (int i = 0; i <PolygonBase.Count; ++i) 
{
    PolygonBase[i] = PolygonBase[i] + MousePos;
}
```

But using [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't:

```
PolygonBase.ForEach(v => v += MousePos);
```

Ideas?

Comment: perhaps the foreach returns a new list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your current code is simply re-assigning the local variable `v` to a new value - it doesn't refer back to the original value in the list. It's the equivalent of writing:

```
foreach(int v in PolygonBase)
{
    v += MousePos;
}
```

To write back to the original value, use [`ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
PolygonBase.ConvertAll(v => v += MousePos);
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks. I was looking to get a foreach by reference but thats way too C++ for c#...